# Shaking in dragging object

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mousemove, mousedown

I am new to C#.
I have been testing in C# (wpf) with MouseDown and MouseMove. Try to create a simple ellipse that can be dragged with the click and movement of the mouse, within a canvas.
All good until I run the code and I see that when I drag the ellipse it shakes.
I know for some it's not a problem, but for me it is.
Next the code in xaml that I use.

```
<Canvas>
        <Ellipse x:Name="circulito" Fill="#FFFDC347" Height="100" Stroke="Black"  Width="100"
        MouseDown="circulito_MouseDown"
        MouseMove="circulito_MouseMove"/>
</Canvas>
```

Next the code in c#.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Point coor;
        Point coorPutin;

        private void circulito_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            coor.X = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
            coor.Y = Canvas.GetTop(this);
        }

        private void circulito_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            coorPutin = e.GetPosition(circulito);                        

            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(circulito, coor.X + coorPutin.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(circulito, coor.Y + coorPutin.Y);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code that is in the question so we can replicate. You don't have a routine for `circulito_MouseUp`, this should generate a `CS1061` error.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the "MouseUp = circulito_MouseUp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All good until I run the code and I see that when I drag the ellipse it shakes

The reason for this is because of your `circulito_MouseMove` routine. You don't need to check if the button is down or not also you are trying to set the canvas, this wont work, you need to set the element (Ellipse) `TopProperty` and `LeftProperty`. Please see below for working solution.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Ellipse _ellipse;
        private Point? _coor;

        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void circulito_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
            _coor = e.GetPosition(_ellipse);
        }

        private void circulito_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ellipse == null)
                return;

            _ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(this).X - _coor.Value.X);
            _ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(this).Y - _coor.Value.Y);
        }

        private void circulito_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => _ellipse = null;

    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp12.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"       
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        MouseMove="circulito_MouseMove"
        >
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse x:Name="circulito"
                 Width="100"
                 Height="100"
                 Fill="#FFFDC347"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 MouseLeftButtonDown="circulito_MouseDown"
                 MouseLeftButtonUp="circulito_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                 MouseMove="circulito_MouseMove"
                 />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Please note in the `MainWindow.xaml` `Window` element, you need to handle the `MouseMove` event as well...

```
 MouseMove="circulito_MouseMove"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `MouseMove` you should use the position of the mouse within the canvas. Therefore assign it a name

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
```

Then you can set the position of the ellipse with

```cs
public void circulito_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
        var coorPutin = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        Canvas.SetLeft(circulito, coorPutin.X - coor.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(circulito, coorPutin.Y - coor.Y);
    }
}
```

Also, you must subtract the initial position you got from `MouseDown`, since you want to set the top/left position of the ellipse above and and to the left of the mouse position to maintain the relative position of the mouse cursor in the ellipse.

`Canvas.GetLeft(this);` will return `NaN` (not a number) if it has not been initialized. Therefore it is better to use

```cs
public void circulito_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    coor = e.GetPosition(circulito);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answering me Codexer.
The xaml code leaves it the same.
In the end just change the c # code to the following.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Point coor;

        private void circulito_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            coor = e.GetPosition(circulito);
        }

        private void circulito_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                circulito.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(this).X - coor.X);
                circulito.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(this).Y - coor.Y);
            }
        }
    }
```